# Trying to install to USB HDD

Tags: installation, usb

I want to install to an external USB HDD.  Drive is currently formatted with one NTFS partition.  Booted from CD.  Selected something else.  Selected dev/sdb.  Hit Install Now.  Get error that says "no root file system defined  Please orrect this from the partitioning menu"  Not sure what to do here.  Want to make sure I do not mess up my internal HDD.  Please provide directions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the inside of the computer you can detach the power cable of the internal HDD (when the system is powered down of course). Then you can boot normally from CD and follow the normal installation procedure to install on your external USB HDD. The only issue with this method is that you need to manually configure GRUB and change the BIOS boot priority to first USB, then HDD.